# Child view rendered into Application breaks parent

Tags: ember.js

I think this is best explained with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/666/

When you click on `foo` everything goes as expected, click on `bar` and then go back to `foo`.  I get a connectOutlet exception in the console.  What I'm trying to achieve is for the child route (bar) to overtake where the parent was drawn.

I know a lot of you will say, "well, why not make it a separate route and just modify the path property of the route," that isn't an option in this case since I'm depending on the parent model and controller to be there.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('foo', function() {
        this.route('bar');
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    redirect: function() { this.transitionTo('foo');} 
});

App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});

App.FooBarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
  templateName: 'foo/bar',
  renderTemplate: function() {

      /***** THE OFFENDING CODE ******/
      this.render(this.templateName, {
          into: 'application',
          outlet: 'main'
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that the `foo` route is part of the `foo/bar` route (`foo/bar` will be rendered into `foo` by default, since they are nested). You could use the `foo/index` route, which automatically exists if you specify sub-routes, or alternative set up another sub-route.

Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/667/).